# Python error, no results on the internet openai-gym

Tags: python, openai-gym

```
import gym
env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1")
env.reset()
env.render()
env.step(1)
env.render()
```

```
Something went wrong with pygame. This should never happen.
  File "C:\Users\ardgn\OneDrive\Belgeler\GitHub\Kutuphaneler-cheatsheets\GYMLibraryOPENAI", line 7, in <module>
    env.render()
```

This is the error I get when I use the above code

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: where do you run it? `pygame` wasn't created to run remotly on internet. And If you run it on server then it may not have GUI to display graphics and this can make problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code works for me if I add `render_mode="human"`

```
import gym

env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1", render_mode="human")
env.reset()

env.render()
env.step(1)
env.render()
```

without `render_mode="human"` (or `render_mode="rgb_array"`) it doesn't initiate `Surface` in `PyGame` in line [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py#L286%5D), and this makes problem.

And this displays text `"Something went wrong with pygame. This should never happen."`

```
        if self.window_surface is None:
            pygame.init()

            if mode == "human":
                pygame.display.init()
                pygame.display.set_caption("Frozen Lake")
                self.window_surface = pygame.display.set_mode(self.window_size)
            elif mode == "rgb_array":
                self.window_surface = pygame.Surface(self.window_size)

        assert (
            self.window_surface is not None
        ), "Something went wrong with pygame. This should never happen."
```

---

**BTW:**

I see that mode `"human"` also runs `render()` automatically in every [step()](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py#L244) and [reset()](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py#L255)

```
def step(self, a):
    transitions = self.P[self.s][a]
    i = categorical_sample([t[0] for t in transitions], self.np_random)
    p, s, r, t = transitions[i]
    self.s = s
    self.lastaction = a

    if self.render_mode == "human":
        self.render()
    return (int(s), r, t, False, {"prob": p})

def reset(
    self,
    *,
    seed: Optional[int] = None,
    options: Optional[dict] = None,
):
    super().reset(seed=seed)
    self.s = categorical_sample(self.initial_state_distrib, self.np_random)
    self.lastaction = None

    if self.render_mode == "human":
        self.render()
    return int(self.s), {"prob": 1}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Code from some tutorials - it uses `render_mode="human"`.

```
import gym

env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1", render_mode="human")

observation, info = env.reset()

for _ in range(1000):
    observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())

    if terminated or truncated:
        observation, info = env.reset()

env.close()
```

Comment: Thanks,this worked.I haven't seen it in the docs

Comment: BTW: you could check source code for [FrozenLake-v1](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py) it uses `render_mode` to render automatically. But maybe there is also some `if render_mode: ...` which initiate PyGame.

Comment: I am really new to algorithms,ai so I am trying to learn step by step.Would appreciate any sources.

Comment: in answer I added links to source code and explanations.